# React Native Android Debug Keystore

Tags: android, react-native, api-key

Question about generating API Keys for Android in React Native.

I'm referencing these:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

What I'm wondering is, is how do I setup a debug API key for android if I'm NOT running on an emulator? I know I can use this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

if I want to create a debug.keystore that the emulator can look at, but how does this work for when I want to compile, build an apk, and run on my device? Do I have to set a pointer to it in gradle.properties? Does React Native know to look in that folder for the debug.keystore, and incorporate it into the apk? I'm not really sure how these things work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

cd android/app/

run:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: The created `debug.keystore` file needs to be moved to `~/.android/` directory. Then rerun `npx react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 9):

Well turns out i just needed to rerun react-native run-android, didn't get my latest change in.

From the looks of it, by default android's settings will look at ~/.android for the debug keystore.

Comment: where we can set alias and password in react native project ?

Comment: @AshokDevatwal most likely in `Project folder\android\app\build.gradle` in `signingConfigs` section